# How to display the found matches of preg_match function in PHP?

Tags: php

I am using the following to check if links exist on file.php:

```
$fopen = fopen('file.php', 'r');

$fread = fread($fopen, filesize('file.php'));

$pattern = "/^<a href=/i";

if (preg_match($pattern, $fread)) {
    echo 'Match Found';
} else {
    echo 'Match Not Found';
}
```

if I `echo preg_match($pattern, $fread)` I get a boolean value, not the found matches. I tried what was on the php.net manual and did this:

```
preg_match($pattern, $fread, $matches);
```

then when I echoed $matches I got "Array" message. So I tried a foreach loop and when that didn't display anything I tried $matches[0] and that too outputted nothing.

So how does one go about displaying the matches found?

### EDIT

Here is the only content of file.php:

```
<a href="">Hello</a>

<a href="http://google.com">Hello</a>

<a href="/index.html">Hello</a>
```

Comment: Read the manual about PCRE backreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the links you're looking for to actually show up you need to have match groups within your regular expression: (note I also added the `m` modifier to deal with multiple lines)

```
$pattern = "/^<a href=(.*?)>/im";
```

Then, if you just want to visualize the contents of that match result array for debugging you can use [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r).

```
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $fread, $matches)) {
    echo 'Match Found';
    print_r($matches);
} else {
    echo 'Match Not Found';
}
```

Comment: That is not an answer. It should be a comment below the question.

Comment: @Marc: this is most certainly an answer to "how to display found matches"

Comment: This outputs: Array ( [0] => and not the actual links that were found.

Comment: @Eric, it outputs your matches to the expression, you may need to add groups...see my edit in a minute from now.

Comment: now it outputs:   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => "" ) )    . I posted the contents of file.php in my edit.

Comment: The code on the ideone site works, the regex is slightly different on that one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The answer has been changed since my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the HTML document

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('file.php');
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
  echo simplexml_import_dom($node)->asXML(), '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: `$matches` is an array of arrays, this will print "Array" several times.

Comment: This outputs Match not Found even though there are links in the file being read.

Comment: @Eric - how about using `>=` instead just greater than 1 ? **PS** your pattern only return single match no matter how many lines of files you have

Comment: @Mark E - is valid, OP did not said using `preg_match_all`

Comment: nope >= outputs same thing. I posted the contents of file.php in my edit.

Comment: +1 for solving the real problem rather than just what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @ajreal whoah thanks, this is even better. Sorry I gave the best answer before seeing your edit.